# Host the site on my computer and make is available on internet

Tags: apache, dns, xampp, hosting, web-hosting

I have the following config on my computer:
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Server installed: Apache2 (XAMPP)

I have static IP bound on my computer (Let's say 100.100.100.100)

I have developed my website on the localhost and now I want to point my IP address on my localhost so that my website should be accessible on internet

How can I do that?

P.S.: I obviously can use the shared/dedicated hosting but I don't want to go for that and my computer has 24*7 internet + power.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can adding NAT rules to you router, if your Apache server use port 80 and 443 you could try NAT these ports from 100.100.100.100 to your external IP address or dynamic dns name (if you have one).

I think is better if you register a dyndns name, if you don't have a static external ip address.